# How arrays inside parentheses works?

Tags: javascript

In Codefights I found this solution to one of their challenges:

```js
alternatingSums = a => a.reduce((accum,value,i) => (accum[i&1] += value, accum), [0,0])
```

This gives the same result:

```js
alternatingSums = a => a.reduce((accum,value,i) => {
    accum[i&1] += value
    return accum
}, [0,0])
```

The part I can't understand is why enclosing two arrays inside parentheses return the array with the accum added in the correct index.

I can't find any documentation about this so I made some experiments trying to figure how this works, but I'm still struggled with this:

```js
const a = [1,2]

console.log( (a) ) // return [1,2]
console.log( (a,a) ) // return [1,2]
console.log( (a,a,a) ) // return [1,2]

console.log( (a[0]) ) // return 1
console.log( (a[0],a) ) // return [1,2]
console.log( (a[0],a,a) ) // return [1,2]

console.log( (a[0]+=1) ) // return 2, a[0] is incremented
console.log( (a[0]+=1,a) ) // return [3,2], a[0] is incremented
console.log( (a[0]+=1,a,a) ) // return [4,2], a[0] is incremented
```

Comment: *"I can't find any documentation about this"* => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions :-)

Comment: Also read up on comma operator

Comment: (a,b,c) is an expression, not an array. a, b, and c are evaluated, in this order, and the whole expression evaluates to c.

Comment: This is one of the common *abusages* of the comma operator, wedging two expressions into a concise body rather than just writing a verbose body. It saves a few characters, and costs readability and maintainability. But at Codefights, I'm guessing brevity outweighs readability and maintainability. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The part I can't understand is why enclosing two arrays inside parentheses return the array with the accum added in the correct index.

`(accum,value,i)` and `(accum[i&1] += value, accum)` aren't arrays. Arrays use `[]`, not `()`.

`(accum,value,i)` is the parameter list of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). We know that because the next token is `=>`.

`(accum[i&1] += value, accum)` is the *body* of the arrow function, specifically a *concise body*. We know that because it immediately follows `=>` and doesn't start with a `{` (which would start a verbose body). That concise body uses the [grouping operator (`()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) around a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma) expression. The comma operator is one of JavaScript's more interesting operators: It evaluates its left-hand operand, throws that value away, then evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that as its result value. Here, it's being used for the left-hand operand's *side effect* of updating `accum[i&i]`'s value.

Since the `(accum[i&1] += value, accum)` is the expression that makes up the concise body of the arrow function, its result (`accum`) is used as the return value of the function.

Your code block after *"This gives the same result"* is a perfect translation of that arrow function's concise body into a verbose body with `return` statement (nice one!), and does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I understand arrow functions, but wasn't clear to me how (accum[i&1] += value, accum) worked.